# What happens when multiple Remix.run loaders all throw redirects?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Skimming throught the FAQ of Remix.run, I noticed [here](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/faq#how-can-i-have-a-parent-route-loader-validate-the-user-and-protect-all-child-routes) that the recommended way to protect a route is to essentially force the loaders `throw` a `redirect`.

What I find difficult wrapping my head around though is **what happens when multiple loaders throw a redirect for a single route**? What would be the expected browser behaviour in this case?

**Example**:
Assume visiting `/protected-route` involves calling 2 loaders. Both loaders are configured to `throw` a redirect to `/login` when a user in unathenticated. What would happen to the browser in this case? Is it expected to visit a route twice? What if the redirect locations are different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that Remix handles the redirects. Even though it calls all loaders in parallel, it still waits until they all resolve before processing. If any loader response is a redirect, it will redirect to the first redirect in the route tree from root to leaf route. So */parent* loader redirect will supercede the */parent/child* loader redirect.

```js
// call loaders in parallel from root to leaf route
const responses = await Promise.all([loaderRoot, loaderParent, loaderChild])

// find first response that is a redirect
const redirectResponse = responses.find(response => isRedirect(response))
if (redirectReponse) {
  return redirectResponse
}
// no redirects so continue processing
```

Comment: Great answer and great handling from Remix! Thank you!